# How to manipulate data coming from a React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React from "react";

class A extends React.Component {
  handleMap = (letter, index) => <div key={index}>{letter}</div>;

  render() {
    const data = ["t", "e", "s", "t"];
    return data.map(this.handleMap);
  }
}

export default A;
```

I have this component called A where it returns an Array of Nodes.

```
class B extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const test = <A />;
    // I want to manupulate the data coming into here. Particaullry 
    // I want to split the array into two seprate arrays. How can I do this?

    return (
      <div>
        {/* I can either put {test} here or <A/> and it will render*/}
        {test}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

How can I manipulate "data" in order to split the array into two arrays?

i want to achieve something like so in my render method

```
const data1 = [<div>t</div>, <div>e</div>]
const data2 = [<div>s</div>, <div>t</div>]
```

Comment: I don't think you can. Why would you want to split up a component like this?

Comment: Could you let us know what why you are attempting to do this? There is probably a better way to accomplish whatever goal you have.